# Return a String from If statement in swift

Tags: swift

I have this function to modify a string.

```
let offset = "01:00"

func newOffset() {
    let offset12 = String(offset.prefix(1))
    if offset12.contains("0") {
        
        let offset13 = offset.suffix(4)
        let offset14 = offset13.prefix(3).replacingOccurrences(of: ":", with: ".")
        
    }
}
```

However I don't know how im supposed to get the value out of the function and assign it to a new variable. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
let offset2 = newOffset()
```

Comment: You will need to return *something*, unless you mark the return type as an optional `String?`.

Comment: You should read up on functions in the [Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html) book.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take arguments in the function and return a  string in the function too. Here is the code:

```
func newOffset(offset: String) -> String
{
    let offset12 = String(offset.prefix(1))
    if offset12.contains("0") {
        
        let offset13 = offset.suffix(4)
        let offset14 = offset13.prefix(3).replacingOccurrences(of: ":", with: ".")
        return offset14
    }
    return offset
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var offset2 = ""


func newOffset() -> String {
    let offset12 = String(offset.prefix(1))
    if offset12.contains("0") {
        let offset13 = offset.suffix(4)
        offset2 = offset13.prefix(3).replacingOccurrences(of: ":", with: ".")
        
        
    }
    return(offset2)
}
```